# What if Jesus choose not to be crucified?

Tags: life-of-jesus, nature-of-god, crucifixion, free-will

Matthew 26:53

> Do you think I cannot call on my Father, and he will at once put at my
> disposal more than twelve legions of angels?

John 10:18

> No one takes it from me, but I lay it down of my own accord. I have
> authority to lay it down and authority to take it up again. This
> command I received from my Father."

Jesus said he had to die in order to fulfill the scripture. But, what **if** he actually did what he said in Matthew 26:53 and John 10:18?

Wouldn't it mean that he could actually sin even though he is a God who is supposed to be incapable of sin?

Or, is this the same question as "Can God create a stone so heavy that He couldn't lift it?"

Comment: Please see the Tour and the Help (below, bottom left) where you will see that philosophical questions (such as hypothetical questions) are off-topic on this Christianity-based website. Welcome to SE-C.

Comment: The traditional interpretation of Jesus being God is an unbiblical construct. You are correct, Jesus could have sinned, or the whole temptation thing was a farce! Why else would we read in Heb 5:7 Jesus praying to be saved from death - and this is not the death on the cross. What verse suggests Jesus was incapable of sin?

Comment: @user47952...i completely reject the statement "Jesus being God is an unbiblical construct". That is false and there are plenty of texts in the Bible that unequivocably prove the complete opposite to be true (perhaps I am misunderstanding what you mean by "traditional interpretation"?)The Biblical God is defined as the following 3 entities 1. the father, 2. the son, and 3. the holy spirit. These are  God, he is not a separate entitity to any of them. So the unique characteristic Jesus has, he is both God and man at  the same time. When one thinks about it, thats an amazing attribute!

Comment: @Primordiarch...Satan tempted Jesus after 40 days in the wilderness, i think specifically because he was human and was absolutely capable of sinning! The temptation Jesus faced was in many ways no different to that of Adam and Eve (who were both created perfect and without sin).

Comment: @Adam if Jesus is God and God cannot be tempted - let alone sin, then Jesus cannot be God. All Jesus said of himself was, 'I am a man who has told you the truth' John 8:40 - so you calling him God is ok then? Only old men have made him God, you do well to question all they have written. Read the bible not old men - DYOR. All you are quoting is without biblical substance - the man Jesus, son of God, born of Mary, *heir* to all things, has plenty of support - alas, mostly ignored. What kind of God need to be given the Holy Spirit - twice!?

Comment: @Adam "there are plenty of texts in the Bible that unequivocally prove the complete opposite to be true" - this is only true if you read in what is not there. They are called proof texts and are taken out of context. That is called eisegesis. I wish you well on your journey of discovery - hopefully the bible will be your reliable source and not old men - however esteemed they may seem to be.